# Adjust alpha in Canvas Group doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I wrote a little code to make a UI menu fade away.

```
public CanvasGroup CanvasGroup;

private void Start()
    {      
        CanvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }

private void Update()
  {
      if (CanvasGroup.alpha >= 0.0f)
        {
            CanvasGroup.alpha -= 0.2f * Time.deltaTime;                
        }
  }
```

But it doesn't work, any idea where it is wrong?

Comment: are you expecting the children of the group to fade with it?

Comment: Yes. It's a parent object with children UI elements. Could the problem be there? I can manipulate the parent's alpha from the inspector manually (from Canvas Group component) and it affects the children as well, but from the code it doesn't work.

Comment: well the bad news is, I made some code almost word for word what you have (ok i just removed time.deltatime) and mine works - so Im going to suggest this is not on your game object - id also change the name of your variable to something more suitable not to be the same as the class